# Difference between Clock and Operating Frequency

Tags: microcontroller, rf, clock-speed

I am very new to embedded world. I am trying to design a transreciever  system based on RF MCU.

I am looking at ATMEGA64RZAV-10PU from Atmel.

The datasheet says the clock frequency as 10MHz but operating frequency as 2.4 GHz. I believe all frequencies are derived from clock, so is the operating frequency using a PLL to boost the frequency of the clock, or is it something else.

Support will be appreciated a lot!

Best Regards,

Comment: Virtually all microcontrollers have numerous internal clock domains generated via some number of PLLs.

Comment: See also: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=142967.0

Comment: 10MHz is likely the core clock that runs the cpu (or the clock that feeds the pll that feeds the core), 2.4GHz is guaranteed to be the RF frequency the radio runs at (no micro runs at 2.4GHz, that's full blown SoC territory), two different clocks for two different parts of the circuit. All produced by PLLs locked to the 10MHz reference.

Comment: See also: http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/what-atmega64rzav-0. It says ATMEGA64RZAV isn't actually a single chip, but a bundle of two chips. And I'm completely unable to find a datasheet, or even a mention of that thing on Atmel's website. So, I don't know what datahseet you have in your hand, but I doubt it says the MCU operating frequency is 2.4 GHz. No such MCU operates at 2.4 Ghz, as Sam mentioned. 2.4 GHz is just the carrier for the radio part (which is implemented by the AT86RF230 chip, not the MCU chip, anyway).